# Retrofit 2 Get Github Users API always returning null

Tags: api, kotlin, retrofit, github-api

I tried to get json from the https://github.com/users.
I want to show username : yehezkiell like https://github.com/yehezkiell.
The retrofit showing success result, but its always return null. I'm new in this retrofit, please help

this my code

```
 val postService = DataRepository.create()

    postService.getUser("yehezkiell").enqueue(object : Callback<Users>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Users>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("retrofitnya","gagal ${t}")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Users>?, response: Response<Users>?) {
            Log.e("retrofitnya","berhasil")

            val data = response?.body()
            Log.e("retrofitnya","berhasil ${data?.name}")


        }

    })
```

Retrofit Instance

```
interface RetrofitInstance {

    @GET("users/{username}")
    fun getUser(@Path("username") username:String ): Call<Users>

}
```

Data repo

```
   object DataRepository {
    fun create(): RetrofitInstance {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("https://github.com")
                .build()
        return retrofit.create(RetrofitInstance::class.java)
    }
}
```

Users.kt

```
open class Users {


    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    open var name: String? = null

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    open var username: String? = null

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    open var email: String? = null
}
```

Comment: How does `Users` look like? Might be an issue with _Gson_.

Comment: only searilazation of username, email, and id

Comment: paste log cat stacktrace here

Comment: Theres no logg sir, its just returning null from here 
Log.e("retrofitnya","berhasil ${data?.name}")

Comment: If you state the `Users` class only contains `username` and it actually has a `name` property, this might be missconfigured. Also another question: Is `data` null as well?

Answer (score 1):

For debugging process, instead of de-serialization to `Users` object immediately after response, should we do somethings like these? :

1. De-serialize it to plain string first.

```
interface RetrofitInstance {

    @GET("users/{username}")
    fun getUser(@Path("username") username: String): Call<String>

}
```

2. Just log that string to show what we really get.

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>?, response: Response<String>?) {
    val responseBody = response?.body() ?: ""
    Log.e("retrofitnya","response body as string = ${responseBody}")
}
```

3. (If we want to use it as `Users` after that) do manually de-serialize it.

```
val user: Users = Gson().fromJson(responseBody, Users::class.java)
```

If it is not too confidential, plz give us how you declare that `Users` data object like, for example, this Foo and Bar.

```
data class Foo(
    @SerializedName("bar") val bar: Bar?
)

data class Bar(
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String?
)
```

Comment: You can see my users class

Comment: Then, I tried your solution but its still give me null. This my log
12-31 17:17:35.193 3564-3564/com.example.yehezkiel.retrofitboilerplate E/retrofitnya: berhasil
12-31 17:17:35.194 3564-3564/com.example.yehezkiel.retrofitboilerplate E/retrofitnya: response body as string = null

one thing, I also tried to catch response code. its shows me 404

Comment: Oh...

After taking a close look to our "URL", I guess that you are trying to get something from GitHub REST API instead of Html data from github [dot] com.


~I will show you in next comment.~

Comment: Ok, there are no need to show anymore cuz you found that point :).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by myself, actually its my silly miss understanding which is that end point is wrong.

```
In my wrong code
   object DataRepository {
    fun create(): RetrofitInstance {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("https://github.com")
                .build()
        return retrofit.create(RetrofitInstance::class.java)
    }
}
```

That wrong end point is

```
https://github.com
```

The true one is

```
https://api.github.com/
```